# ResponseStream from API results in empty values on deserializing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Returning data from my API and deserializing it in the client controller, the content seems to empty. I've verified that the API is returning valid data, and it the "count" in the response is accurate. However, the data when serialized is seems not be initialized.

Not quite sure where to look for what's causing the issue. My best theory is that the data is being deserialized before it's materialized due to the async, but that doesn't explain why the count is correct (2 records).

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
  var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("APIClient");

  var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/api/AppUsers");
        
  var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  { 
    using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())        
    {
      var users = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IList<AppUser>>(responseStream);

      return View(new IndexViewModel(users));
    }
  }
  else if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized ||
          response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden) 
  {
    return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Authorization");
  }
  throw new Exception("Problem accessing the API");
  
}
```

API Method which is called

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAppUsers()
{
  var users = _appUserService.ListAppUsers();
  return Ok(users);
}
```

[image]

Calling the API Method directly shows the 2 rows returned as expected
[image]

After some debugging, I noticed that the json structure returned from the API is having first letter in property name as lowercase, but the AppUser class have first letter UpperCase. Not sure why this happens, but that's the reason why the deserialization fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After noticing the properties changing from upper case to lower case on the JSON object, the solution will be to either force JSON to PascalCase as the default now is camelCase

https://codeopinion.com/asp-net-core-mvc-json-output-camelcase-pascalcase/

or I need to consider the camelCase on deserialization.

This issue stole several hours from my life :/
Hope this post can save some hours for somebody else.

One solution would be to disable the defaulting

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
  options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
})
  .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
  .AddJsonOptions(options =>
 {
   options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null; //to avoid defaulting to camelCase
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to deserialize to List instead to IList:

```
var users = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<AppUser>>(responseStream);
```

I think that you should remove ConfigureAwait(false) so you can remain in the same synchronizaton context.

For more info check this link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/

Comment: I think I've already tried that, but to make sure I removed it now and re-ran the application. It does not have any effect. The list still contains the items with the "empty" values

Comment: Can you add AppUsers code to your question?

Comment: Sure, I'll add it now

Comment: I updated my answer. No other ideas.

Comment: Using LIST instead of ILIST had also no effect on the results. Thanks for your input, I appreciate that you took the time. I will just have to continue my search :)

Comment: It seems that what's causing the issue is that the "class" is altered which causes the deserialization to fail. Notice that the propertynames in the class is first letter capitalized, but in the response from the API the json property names, the first letter is not capitalized. Not sure why this happens yet, but that's the problem.

Comment: Nice catch :) Usually we miss the small things.